# Magento increase CPU system usage after 1.7.0.2 update to 1.9.3.3

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, upgrade, performance

After I updated Magento, it starts to use more CPU than usual as you can see below. After 05-07, CPU system time increases, just at the day I updated Magento to 1.9.3.3.

[image: After 05-07 cpu system time increase, the day i deploy Magento 1.9.3.3 update]

In this second image you can see CPU usage closer. After clearing cache, CPU system usage drops (between 21:00 and 22:00):

[image: cpu system drop after cache clear]

Is there any explanation for this high CPU system usage after Magento update?

I guess cache is more used in this new Magento version, so that it uses more system to read the cache.

Is this ok? Should I care?

Answer (score 0):

[iowait time](https://serverfault.com/a/12714/290960) is what you want to watch out for. Other than that its hard to give you good advice other than at first glance it looks fine.